# Best way to display images in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android app which retrive PC's informations from a database, upload the relative images of the PC to the server and also get back the PC's URL of the images for displaying. Everything works like a charm, for all of the 3 part I use a WCF service, deployed on remote IIS server.

The images are stored in a server's virtual directory, so you can copy the URL and paste it in the browser and the image appear without problems.

As I use a dynamic view of the images, I implemented the method below for creating them:

```
private void DisplayAttechedIMages(List<string> list_images_url)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list_images_url.Count; i++)
    {
        Image pic = new Image
        {
            HeightRequest = 250,
            WidthRequest = 150,
            Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(list_images_url[i])),
        };
    }
}
```

This is only the part where I create them, now I need to add them to a container, I tried to use `<Grid>` inside a `<ScrollView>`, but the result isn't good, because the visualization results with low performance (lagging, low response and bad resize).

Also I tried `<ViewCell>` inside `<TableView>` but the results are pretty the same.

This results could depend by the device?

So what is the best way to display image using the URLs?

Comment: For better performance, you can try [Glidex](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/glidex). Though it's only for android 
Other than that you need to cache the images

Answer (score 0):

> but the result isn't good, because the visualization results with low performance (lagging, low response and bad resize).

About lagging and low response , this need cache for Image .And bad resize , there is a property inside `Image` :

The `Aspect` property determines how the image will be scaled to fit the display area:

- `Fill` - Stretches the image to completely and exactly fill the display area. This may result in the image being distorted.
- `AspectFill` - Clips the image so that it fills the display area while preserving the aspect (ie. no distortion).
- `AspectFit` - Letterboxes the image (if required) so that the entire image fits into the display area, with blank space added to the top/bottom or sides depending on whether the image is wide or tall.

You can choose one to fit your best wants .Here is the forms doc about [displaying images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#display-images).

Here , I will recommand you **[FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading)** Nuget Packaget to have a try , it optimizeds the url image with cache used .

```
var cachedImage = new CachedImage() {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    WidthRequest = 300,
    HeightRequest = 300,
    CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
    DownsampleToViewSize = true,
    RetryCount = 0,
    RetryDelay = 250,
    BitmapOptimizations = false,
    LoadingPlaceholder = "loading.png",
    ErrorPlaceholder = "error.png",
    Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg"
};
```

You can refer to its [official sample](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#c) to have a try .